# Using rewind() returns an error, removing it allows code to run fine

Tags: c, fopen, fread, fseek, rewind

**Summary**

I am trying to create a program that converts the contents of a file into a string.

I `fseek` to the end of the file then `ftell` to find the length in order to use the length for `fread`.

Problem is, I have to `fseek` back to the start of the file in order to read from the beginning, or else it will read starting from the end of the file, which is obviously a problem.

Problem is, using `rewind()` returns an error for some reason.

Note that removing the `rewind()` line from my code allows it to run without errors, but (null) is printed because its reading from the end of the file. This is why I'm assuming `rewind()` is the problem.

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE* dictionary = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    fseek(dictionary, 0, SEEK_END);
    int len = ftell(dictionary);
    rewind(dictionary);

    char* txt;
    fread(txt, len+1, 1, dictionary);
    printf("%s", txt);
}
```

**Error Message**

```
shell returned 139
```

Comment: `txt` is not assigned any memory ... UB

Comment: `txt` points nowhere. What you see is a manifestation of _undefined behaviour_ (google that).

Comment: OT: always check if `fopen` fails.

Comment: And `fread()`.  Not checking the return value from `fread()` is why you thought your code worked without rewind. Your code didn't work - the `fseek()` call left the file pointer at the end of the file, so the `fread()` call **didn't read anything** and never had to try accessing non-existent memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memory is needed in `txt`:

Change:

```
 char* txt;
 fread(txt, len+1, 1, dictionary);
 printf("%s", txt);
```

To

```
char* txt = malloc(len+1);
if(txt)
{
    fread(txt, len, 1, dictionary);
    txt[len] = 0;//add terminating NULL
    printf("%s", txt);
    free(txt);
}
```

Comment: I suggest you `fread(txt, len, 1, dictionary);` (the actual length) also need `text[len] = '\0';`

Comment: Ok thanks! Also, I thought you needed the len+1 for the file terminating character. @WeatherVane

Comment: Yes, you do need to *allocate* the extra length. But text files don't contain string terminators.

Answer (score 1):

The root of the problem is that `fread()` tries to write the data from the file into `txt`, but `txt` doesn't point to allocated memory. Here's one way to fix it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE* dictionary = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    fseek(dictionary, 0, SEEK_END);
    int len = ftell(dictionary);
    rewind(dictionary);

    char *txt = malloc(len);
    fread(txt, len, 1, dictionary);
    printf("%s", txt);
}
```

I think this worked when `rewind()` was removed because `fread` reached the end of file before writing to the invalid pointer in `txt`.